# How to set swiper thumbs gallery's active slide at first position when slide change?

Tags: javascript, html, css

- I want the image I selected to come on top of the thumbnail.
  something like [https://jsfiddle.net/GabrielS0uza/cuagh0ow/]
  (https://stackoverflow.com)
- But my slider thumbnail works only upto 5 slides in thumbnail
  After 5 slidethumbs, the selected image does not slide to the top
  And I want to adjust the thumbnail so that the selected image slides on top
  of the thumbnail.
- Issue is occured becuse of swiper version is diffrent, I try every possible
  solution that avilable on the internet but not work any solution in new
  version.
  **So please guide me to achieve this**.
  **And here is the link to the coding I did [https://jsfiddle.net/fLc5b2pw/43/](https://stackoverflow.com)**